# Как передать двумерный массив int в функцию?

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь передать двумерный массив а он орет.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void changeValue(int array[5][5])
{
    array[0][0] = 777;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    int array[N][N] = { {0} };

    changeValue(&array);
    std::cout << array[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

1. В целом по задаче нужен двумерный массив int
2. Его нужно передать в другую функцию, в которой будут изменены его элементы
3. Вернуть в main и там сообщить результаты изменения
4. Количество элементов в массиве должно задаваться в процессе выполнения кода.

Comment: у вас просто лишнее получение указателя. `changeValue(array);`  и всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж Вы хотите хранить данные именно в "голом" массиве, придётся проделать такие вот извращения:

```cpp
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void changeValue(int** array)
{
    array[0][0] = 777;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5; // Заменить на int N; cin >> N; для ввода пользовательского размера
    int ** array = new int*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        array[i] = new int[N];

    array[0][0] = 0;

    changeValue(array);
    std::cout << array[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        delete[] array[i];
    delete[] array;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если же конкретный тип контейнера не имеет значения, предлагаю воспользоваться советом из [Cpp core guidlines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines//CppCoreGuidelines) и использовать `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void changeValue(vector<vector<int>> &array)
{
    (*array)[0][0] = 777;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5; // Заменить на int N; cin >> N; для ввода пользовательского размера
    vector<vector<int>> array;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        vector<int> vec(N);
        array.push_back(vec);
    }

    array[0][0] = 0;

    changeValue(array);
    std::cout << array[0][0];

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Во втором случае передавать в функцию именно указатель или ссылку необходимо, чтобы функция изменяла исходное значение, а не его копию.

Comment: На каждый `new` нужен `delete`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, спасибо. Писал наспех, забыл. Хотя, в данной ситуации это необязательно. Программа весьма проста.

Comment: @V-Mor, передавайте `std::vector` по ссылке.

Comment: @isnullxbh Да, так действительно лучше. Почему-то сразу не пришло в голову, спасибо.